Disable Mutual friends add button
How do I change my Facebook settings so that no one not even friends of friends can send me friend requests / add me as a friend?
I.e My sister in-law and I have my husband as a mutual friend but her profile does not allow me to add her as a friend
She has not blocked me.

The strictest setting is "Friends of Friends". If you have mutual friends and the button does not show up, they must have denied or deleted a friend request from you.
How do I delete a friend request on Facebook?
